# My python module only works inside the directory I installed it from Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm having some trouble installing PIL (python image library). Basically when I run,

```
python setup.py install
```

inside of the installer directory I get

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/tk.h:78:11: fatal error: 
  'X11/Xlib.h' file not found
   include <X11/Xlib.h>
```

but I can import PIL with no problems inside the installer directory and it seems to work fine. However if I go into any other directory

```
import PIL
```

returns,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `pip` to install this? Also, what version of Python are you on? I think you need `Pillow` for Python 3

Comment: @roganjosh no reason not to use `pip` just a fault of habit. I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Try `pip install PIL`. The reason you are able to successfully load the module inside the directory is simple: any .py file that is in the same directory as the python script you are running can be imported as a module. The "other" modules that can be imported are stored in a directory that is in your PATH.